# Does Fedora's inst.gpt command exist in other distros?

Tags: fedora, boot, gpt

I have recently found this inst.gpt boot flag in Fedora useful as it allows me to say up a GPT drive on a non-UEFI BIOS system, does it also exist in a different form on other distros?
If not would it be hard to include or add as a new feature?
To add some detail, I have looked for a similar boot flag on all the major distros I know about (except Gentoo and Arch) and I couldn't find it.

Comment: No need for special boot flags, Linux doesn't use them. It's always possible to install in BIOS mode with GPT drives with a small partition added. Windows has that limitiation, not any major Linux distro.

Comment: Do you mean installing manually or by using the automated partitioning setup tool? If it's the latter, could you point me to what steps I should take as simply adding an EFI partition and then letting the installer handle the rest would work for me?

Comment: Making a 2MiB partition at the start of the drive, with partition type set to "BIOS Boot Partition" or `ef02` will make GPT disks boot on non-EFI systems.

Answer (score 0):

This directive is Anaconda2 (an installer) specific.  That means that it is available on Red Hat, CentOS and Fedora.

Yes you could add the directive to other installers but that would require you to build your own custom version of an installer.